# cassandraへのマルチスレッドによるselect

Tags: java, cassandra

cassandraへのマルチスレッドによるselectはできますか？

現在、datastaxのjavaドライバを使用して以下のようなコードでselect文を発行しています。

```
ResultSet results = session.execute(statement);
```

このコードを含む部分をマルチスレッドで処理していますが、
マルチスレッド処理せずに、直列に処理をしてもtotalの処理時間がほぼ代わりません。

例）3スレッドで、それぞれ0.1sec, 0.3sec, 0.5secかかる場合、
マルチスレッドで実行してもほぼ0.8secになる

Comment: session を取得しているコードを追記できますでしょうか？全てのスレッドで同じ session を使っているのかも？と思いましたので。

Comment: 全てのスレッドで同じsessionを使っています。
ではsessionプーリングを実装するなりして、複数のsessionを保持する仕組みにすると改善の可能性があるということでしょうか